# Calling web services from a SharePoint Silverlight webpart

Tags: silverlight, web-services, sharepoint

We are designing a system that will use Silverlight webparts. These webpart will communicate with backend systems via web services.

What I am wondering is which route they should take:

- Web services on the SharePoint server that talk to the backend service via business connectivity services.
- A call via the service bus
- A call directly to the backend service

Is any one of these better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on requirements that you've not detailed here.

Negatives for via the sp server.

- Add's extra latency
- Adds overhead to the sp box
- Makes it a little harder to do authentication (double hop)

Positives

- Gives you more control - the SP web service could for example, implement caching or extra 
  security rules